# how to add time in seconds in csv file using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to update the date and time(`MM/dd/yyyy` `HH:mm:ss tt`) in a csv file. After the update the time is incorrect. For example, if I update 
"1/4/2016 1:10:13 PM" it is updating as "1/4/2016 1:10". But If I update "1/4/2016 1:10:13PM"(without space for PM), it is updating correctly. Please refer my code below.

```
string str = "1/4/2016 1:10:13 PM";
FileWriter.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: How you are viewing the csv file ? as raw or using Microsoft excel or other CSV editor? Did you checked in the original file i.e opening in text editor ?

Comment: I am viewing using Microsoft excel only.If I opened in wordpad it is showing correctly.

Comment: I guess When u give without space for PM, it(Excel) is treating as text . Hence it is showing as it is.

Comment: See how your code is reading the string from the CSV. If it's what you expect (i.e. the same as in Excel), the fact that you're reading from a CSV is irrelevant.

Comment: Your issue is obviously with Excel, not C#.  Excel is notorious for making decisions about how to display formatted data.  If you want Excel to display the data the way you want then it's got to be written in a way that Excel will interpret that way.  That's got nothing to do with C#.  Your C# code is working exactly as it should.  If you want to work out what Excel is doing then you can test that simply by editing in Notepad and then viewing in Excel.  Again, this is an Excel issue, not a C# issue.

Comment: Please don't use the quote formatting (`>`) for things that aren't quotes. I see all your questions have been asked with your text formatted this way, and then later changed by others.